# DDD Runtime (?) error

Tags: c, debugging, runtime-error, ddd-debugger

While i was using DDD for debugging some C code i wrote, it came out with this strange error when i tryed to execute a line in which was a malloc

> > $/BRIS/src/malloc.c : No such file or directory
> >
> > $/BRIS/src/ is where my compiled C file is placed

It came out even with other basic C functions like printf and others; the strange thing it's that i ran preveously that code with DDD and i didn't get any error.

Do you know what is happening? These error continues to pop even if i re-open DDD

Comment: As a guess your executable has problems with the symbol table.  Recompile with gcc: optimizations OFF -o0, with -g to add symbols, and do not strip the output -- meaning no -s option.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: valgrind was installed and somehow interacted badly with DDD